# Google Search: how to use inurl in this case?

Tags: google-search

I want to exclude  from Google Search result all links that include "news" , "daily" using one query.

Example:

> site.com/path
>
> site2.com/news/path
>
> site3.com/daily/path

I need only

> site.com/path

I try to do:

> query -inurl:news -inurl:daily
>
> query -inurl:news OR -inurl:daily
>
> query -inurl:news AND -inurl:daily

But nothing work.

What query I should to use in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You say the following doesn't work, but it works pretty well for me:

```
query -inurl:news -inurl:daily
```

Can you post a concrete example showing where this doesn't work?